# Why is the angular momentum of blackhole measured by orbital motion of falling objects around it?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, angular-momentum, orbital-motion

When massive star collapsed under it's own weight, it can becomes a blackhole and I have to believe angular momentum is conserved. Since we cannot directly measure the rotation of blackhole, I read that we can infer by observing the orbiting stuffs which seems puzzling to me. How are the angular momentum of blackhole related to the orbital motion of objects around it? How accurate can this approach get?

Comment: Do you know about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging ?

Comment: @PM2Ring: I went to read more about this frame dragging you mentioned and got side tracked, clock at the equator goes faster than at the pole how awesome is that.